# Entity framework - The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express with SQL Servre authentication and remote connections enabled although I am working locally.

My `web.config` connection string part:

```
<add name="HelpDesk2connect" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=SATURN;Initial Catalog=HelpDesk2;Integrated Security=False;user id=sa;password=*******;multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I am logging in as `sa`

In the controller I get these errors (in this statement: `return View(db.Tickets.ToList());)

> *An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.*
>
> *The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.*

In the page I get this error:

> *[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a LocalDB installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the LocalDB feature is enabled.)]*

Can you help me spot what am I doing wrong?

Thanx in advance

Comment: On a recent project using sqlexpress my connection string data source looks like this: "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: Thanx but I am not using a named instance.

Comment: You need to put the `;` back in. It should be `&quot;`.

Comment: I have it.I removed it just to be presented in stackoverflow editor.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the database specified in the connection string. The second exception seems to be talking about localdb while your connection string points to a database on a separate machine (or non-SqlExpress/non-localDB on your box). If you are using EF5 and you don't have SqlExpress installed EF5 will default to localdb. You seem to be using this default even though you don't seem to have localdb installed. Show how your derived context ctor is implemented and how you instantiate it.